# Отправка формы при переходе на страницу с формой

Tags: javascript, ajax, joomla, компоненты

Имеется связка модуля и компонента в joomla. Модуль включает в себя фильтр который позволяет пользователю выбирать соотвествующие параметры. При отправке данных с модуля (через форму), в компонент выводится соотвествующие результаты, и вместе с результатами выводится аналогичная форма, с помощью которой пользователь может изменить ранее выбранные параметры, на другие. Но эта форма, **на странице компонента**, выводит эти параметры только после того как я нажму кнопку "отправить". До момента нажатия, форма не дает сделать никакого выбора. Посоветуйте как сделать так, чтобы при переходе с модуля на компонент, отправка формы **на компоненте** срабатывала автоматически, и мне не приходилось нажимать на submit.

Answer (score 0):

честно говоря слабо понятна проблема...

в модели которую использует данное представление компонента, должна быть обработка полей из фильтров, метод populateState, который пишет значение фильтров в state 
соответственно в хелпере модуля вы должны должны получить значения этих фильтров из state, чтоб заполнить форму

я так понимаю что вы от всего этого далеки

если фильтры из модуля не работают, попробуйте к названиям полей добавить префикс filter_, то есть названия поля должно выглядеть filter_search, filter_category и тп
если в populateState правильно написана обработка этих фильтров, то должно сработать

Comment: Вот при заполнении и отправки фильтра на этой странице [ссылка](https://studentprograms.ru/ekzamenatsionnye-kursy.html) данные с формы должны попасть на страницу компонента вида programs/, и там уже можно было бы выбирать другие варианты

Comment: Метод populateState описан в модели programs.php, однако в хэлпере никакие их этих значений не принимаются. Названия полей выглядят точно так, как вы описали, с префиксом filter_. Сам этот код не писал, а дорабатываю за разработчика.